# How to configure Renovate to run generateJooq gradle task when jOOQ version is updated?

Tags: java, jooq, renovate

I would like to run the `generateJooq` gradle task automatically whenever Renovate updates the **jOOQ** version.

I use **jOOQ** in my Java project. When Renovate updates it, the library's version is changed, but all auto-generated jOOQ classes are not refreshed. Renovate creates a commit that changes the library but doesn't change the code. As a result, the code is generated when I run first `generateJooq` or `build` after jOOQ's update. It's inconvenient because database changes are added to some next commit which has nothing to do with the database. It would be more concise if auto-generated classes are updated in Renovate's commit.

The problem would be solved e.g. if the gradle task `generateJooq` is run whenever Renovate updates **jOOQ**. I haven't found such an option in Renovate's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on the [`<generatedAnnotation>` flag](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-generate/codegen-generate-annotations/) to produce a `@Generated` annotation, you can quickly compare its jOOQ version value with the `Constants.VERSION` value of the jOOQ library:

#### `@Generated` annotation example:

```java
@Generated(
    value = {
        "https://www.jooq.org",
        "jOOQ version:3.19.0-SNAPSHOT"
    },
    comments = "This class is generated by jOOQ"
)
```

#### `Constants` content:

```
public final class Constants {
    // ...

    public static final String VERSION        = "3.19.0-SNAPSHOT";
}
```

I'm not sure if there's any automated way of doing this already, but it should be simple to quickly script this in Gradle. If you're using this [third party plugin](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin), you might be able to leverage its Gradle task dependency integration to automate this further, without introspecting actual generated code.